# in C#, how can i take an image from a URL and convert to System.Data.Linq.Binary

Tags: c#, linq, image, binary

i am using a library that wants a photo in **System.Data.Linq.Binary** format.  RIght now i just have a URL.  what is the easiest way in C# to convert this link into the **System.Data.Linq.Binary** format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
byte[] raw;
using(var client = new WebClient()) { // in System.Net
    raw = client.DownloadData(url);
}
var binary = new Binary(raw); // in System.Data.Linq
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [`WebClient.DownloadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) is the easiest way:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(yourUrl);
```